# Should I be using JSON or XML when the order of the properties, of the server-returned object, matters?

Tags: mysql, json, xml, reactjs

Client uses ReactJS and server is using Node, Express and MySQL for the db. I'm making a website that allows users to post news articles, e.g. long bodies of text with images inserted at random points inside them. Think of a website like Medium that allows users to write blog posts and insert images at any point.

My issue here lies with how I am to store the information for each article. Originally, I was going to use XML - use  and  tags and represent each article as an XML document. This way, when the server parses the XML document after pulling it from the DB, the order of the elements is preserved.

For example:

```
<<text> /* long body of text (e.g. about 300 - 500 words?) */ </text>
<img> First image path goes here </img>
<text> /* Another body of text! */ </text>
<img> Some cool graph that's relevant for the article </img>
```

When my server tries to parse this XML document, the order is very important. The contents of the first text tag (line 1 in the code sample above) must be parsed first. Then below that should be the first image (line 2). Once the full XML document is parsed, it should be sent to the client, where React will iterate through the returned object and, create a paragraph or image ReactElement for each object.

I use JSON for most things to represent the objects that client and server exchange. But, I am quite aware that within JSON objects, the order of the keys {key: value}, is not preserved. Therefore, it would be possible that (referring to my silly code snippet above), line 2 could be added to my VirtualDOM before line 1, making the outputted order incorrect.

Therefore, should I be using JSON or XML as 1) the format of the object that the server returns and 2) the representation of each article.

Answer (score 1):

Both XML and JSON have the ability to represent data in a way that preserves order. The nearest JSON equivalent to your XML might be:

```
[
  {"text":"long body of text (e.g. about 300 - 500 words?)"},
  {"img":"First image path goes here"},
  {"text":"Another body of text!"},
  {"img":"Some cool graph that's relevant for the article"}
]
```

Because order matters, you have to use an array here.

You could argue that this structure looks pretty strange, and you would be right. JSON was never designed for representing document structures. I would strongly question the wisdom of using JSON to represent free-format articles in the way you are proposing. There are some things JSON does better than XML, and there are other things XML does better than JSON, and your application is firmly in the second category.

Comment: Thanks for the response Michael. Do you mind explaining a bit more as to why the second category (XML's advantages over JSON) is more apt for my application?

Comment: I would want to know an awful lot more about your application, your business requirements, and your project constraints, before making an informed recommendation. But you say it's about "news articles" and "blog posts" with "inserted images", and that certainly sounds rather like a description of an application where you need a markup language rather than a data interchange syntax. Partly because the data model is a much better fit to hierarchically-structured document, partly because the tool-sets around XML are expressly designed for this kind of application.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's JSON data type does not preserve the order however you can store it as a string which will save idempotency. But you lose the ability to use the MySQL JSON functions, which you might be able to live with if your processing is mainly in your application.